# Visual Studio 2022 has No html class intellisense in Razor component

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 17.1 Preview 2.0, I opened a .Net 6 windows forms (with BlazorWebView) program that I was created in a previous version of VS 2022.

While I had not any problem writing this app in an early VS 2022 version, I have two problems now.

1. No intellisense support for class attributes (bootstrap) but intellisense works for style="" .
2. in C# portion of .razor file, opening a brace and pressing enter jumps up one page, So I disabled automatic brace completion, So this problem almost solved.

How to correct the first problem, *no class intellisense*? (the second problem almost solved in vs options and is not urgent).

Comment: I suggest you send feedback to the VS team using the option built into VS (small button in top right of main window, or menu Help > Send Feedback). Especially when using a Preview version, bad things can happen.

Comment: Does it do it in all pages? Does it do it even in a brand new BWASM project with just the basic counter/weather?

Comment: In a standard Blazor Server App or BWASM it is good, But I want it to work also in a WinForm App with Blazor Components, I written some pages before in this win form app using a previous vs 2022 version without any problems.